# JQuery autocomplete UI com PHP retorna somente palavras inteiras

Tags: php, jquery, autocompletar, ui

Estou no meu primeiro projeto com php + MySQL com um input de pesquisa de *palavras* usando o JQuery UI. Todo tutorial que fiz, exibem as palavras a medida que o usuário vai digitando, como uma `substring`. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo **'as'** uma substring de **AS**p, b**AS**ic etc...

Já no meu código não ocorre assim. Ele só exibe quando dá um **match** na palavra inteira.

Por exemplo, eu começo digitando: **abac**  e nada é exibido.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Somente quando eu termino digitando é que a palavra aparece:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria exibir todas as substrings com um mínimo de três letras `minLength: 3`. O que estou deixando passar?

meu código `index.php`:

```html
<input type="text" name="word" class="j_autocomplete" id="word_input">

(...)
// com o script lá embaixo
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    // autocomplete
    $(".j_autocomplete").autocomplete({
      source: 'src/search.php',
      minLength: 3
    });
  });
</script>
```

o `search.php` está assim:

```php
<?php
require('../config.php'); // conexão com o 'db' funcionando!

$return_arr = array();
$userInput = $_GET['term'];

$search = $mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM `palavras` WHERE `palavra` LIKE ? ORDER BY palavra ASC');

$search->bind_param('s', $userInput);
$search->execute();

$getResult = $search->get_result();


while ($row = $getResult->fetch_assoc()) :

  $return_arr[] =  $row['palavra'];
endwhile;

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

### O que estou deixando passar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando se usa o operador LIKE para buscar por partes do texto você precisa informar um 'coringa', no caso do MySQL e na maioria dos bancos relacionais pode usar o % como coringa.

Por exemplo, para pesquisar meu nome usando like, eu poderia usar:

```
SELECT * FROM cliente WHERE nome LIKE 'JHO%'
```

O MySQL vai interpretar essa expressão para retornar todos os clientes em que o campo nome comece com 'JHO', que pode ser JHONNY, JHONY, JHON.

Nesse caso, você pode fazer a consulta de duas maneiras:

```
$search = $mysql->prepare("SELECT * FROM `palavras` WHERE `palavra` LIKE '%?%' ORDER BY palavra ASC");

$search->bind_param('s', $userInput);
$search->execute();
```

ou

```
$search = $mysql->prepare('SELECT * FROM `palavras` WHERE `palavra` LIKE ? ORDER BY palavra ASC');

$search->bind_param('s','%' . $userInput . '%');
$search->execute();
```

Colocar o % no antes de depois do filtro, permite você buscar por partes que podem estar no começo, meio e final do texto.

Comment: acabei de ver esse operador. muito bom. não deu certo, mas o problema é outro. Antes de exibir na tela eu chamo um validateWord() que recebe uma string e não um array, caso o LIKE %% retorne um array da erro de tipo. vejo isso depois.